# Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap for "map"

Tags: clojure

I've obfuscated this code.

Why does this work:

```
(let [
   items [{:var1 x, :var2  x, :var3 (:something x), :var4 (:something2 x)}]

;..........
(my-func items) ; ok
```

whereas this produces an exception:

```
(let [
   items (map (fn [x] ({:var1 x, :var2 x, :var3 (:something x), :var4 (:something2 x)})) (db/get-items-from-db))

    ;..........
    (my-func items) ; error
```

which is

```
 Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap
```

Comment: What are your `items-from-db`?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When we strip it down to the bones, we have this:

```
(map (fn [x] ({:a x :b (:c x)})) '({:c "abc"}))
```

Which produces your error.

The problem is that there are parentheses around the map definition, thus, the map is being treated as a function, and there are no arguments given to it in this case.  Remove the parens, and it works:

```
(map (fn [x] {:a x :b (:c x)}) '({:c "abc"}))
;; ({:a {:c "abc"}, :b "abc"})
```

It would be the same error as trying to do this:

```
(defn func [x]
  ({:a x :b (:c x)}))
```

When in fact you want:

```
(defn func [x]
  {:a x :b (:c x)})
```

It may help to further understand if we remember that a map may be used as a function, with the argument specifying which key's value to return:

```
({:a 1 :b 2} :b)
;; 2
```

though we often do the reverse and use the key as the function:

```
(:b {:a 1 :b 2})
;; 2
```

So we could also remove the error by specifying an argument (in this case `:b`) to the map being created, though it would not produce the implied desired result:

```
(map (fn [x] ({:a x :b (:c x)} :b)) '({:c "abc"}))
;; ("abc")
```